# What is the __del__ method and how do I call it?

Tags: python, oop

I saw a class in which a [`__del__` method](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) is defined. This method is used to destroy an instance of the class. However, I cannot find a place where this method is used. How is this method used? Like that: `obj1.del()`?.

How do I call the `__del__` method?

Comment: For readers: Check out [this video by mCoding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFjuQmlwXgU), which explains how `__del__` works and provides some alternatives to it.

Comment: @InSync "For **readers**: Check out this **video** by mCoding, ..." -- well, rather for those who can't read ;-) (emphasis mine)

Comment: @AndrásAszódi Those who can't read might have screen *readers*.

Comment: @InSync I meant analphabets (functional or otherwise), not people with visual disabilities. But yes, you are right, there are several technologies that can help people suffering from both conditions.

Answer (score 245):

`__del__` is a **finalizer**. It is called when an object is **garbage collected** which happens at some point after all references to the object have been deleted.

In a **simple case** this could be right after you say `del x` or, if `x` is a local variable, after the function ends. In particular, unless there are circular references, CPython (the standard Python implementation) will garbage collect immediately.<sup>*</sup>

However, this is an **implementation detail** of CPython. The only **required** property of Python garbage collection is that it happens *after* all references have been deleted, so this might not necessary happen *right after* and **might not happen at all**.

Even more, variables can live for a long time for **many reasons**, e.g. a propagating exception or module introspection can keep variable reference count greater than 0. Also, variable can be a part of **cycle of references** — CPython with garbage collection turned on breaks most, but not all, such cycles, and even then only periodically.

Since you have no guarantee it's executed, one should **never** put the code that you need to be run into `__del__()` — instead, this code belongs to the `finally` clause of a `try` statement or to a context manager in a `with` statement. However, there are **valid use cases** for `__del__`: e.g. if an object `X` references `Y` and also keeps a copy of `Y` reference in a global `cache` (`cache['X -> Y'] = Y`) then it would be polite for `X.__del__` to also delete the cache entry.

**If you know** that the destructor provides (in violation of the above guideline) a required cleanup, you might want to **call it directly**, since there is nothing special about it as a method: `x.__del__()`. Obviously, you should only do so if you know it can be called twice. Or, as a last resort, you can redefine this method using

```
type(x).__del__ = my_safe_cleanup_method
```

---

* [Reference](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html):

> **CPython implementation detail:** CPython currently uses a reference-counting scheme with (optional) delayed detection of cyclically linked garbage, which collects most objects as soon as they become unreachable [...] Other implementations act differently and CPython may change.

Comment: Whats with `__exit__` in this context? Is it run after or before `__del__` or together?

Comment: You could also use a class variable to tell whether it's already had `__del__` called, so you don't have to worry about a second call.

Comment: Does "might not happen at all" include when the program terminates?

Comment: @AndyHayden: `__del__` methods might not run even at program termination, and even when they do run at termination, writing a `__del__` method that works properly even while the interpreter is busy self-destructing around you requires more careful coding than many programmers apply. (CPython cleanup usually gets `__del__` methods to run at interpreter shutdown, but there are still cases where it isn't enough. Daemon threads, C-level globals, and objects with `__del__` created in another `__del__` can all lead to `__del__` methods not running.)

Comment: @ilyan. python [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=destructor#object.__del__) explains that `__del__` method should not be called a destructor for some reason that I don't know. Do you still think that it is right to call it a destructor?

Comment: @bombs It's not a destructor for the same reason that `__init__` is not a constructor. Neither one actually creates or destroys the object. The `__init__` method initializes an object that already exists by the time it's called (which is why it doesn't return anything either).  Likewise, the object still exists by the time `__del__` exits: it merely does whatever cleanup ("finalization") may be desirable before the actual destruction will take place.

Comment: I have close method written in my class and  __del__ pointing to it. Is it goo practice or should i just have close method and whenver required call it? What difference __del__ method will make to class? On link - https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python. i found below statement which is adding more confusion. "Circular references which are garbage are detected when the option cycle detector is enabled (it’s on by default), but can only be cleaned up if there are no Python-level __del__() methods involved."

Answer (score 119):

I wrote up the answer for another question, though this is a more accurate question for it.

[How do constructors and destructors work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433130/can-someone-here-explain-constructors-and-destructors-in-python-simple-explanat/2433847#2433847)

Here is a slightly opinionated answer.

Don't use `__del__`. This is not C++ or a language built for destructors. The `__del__` method really should be gone in Python 3.x, though I'm sure someone will find a use case that makes sense. If you need to use `__del__`, be aware of the basic limitations per http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html:

- `__del__` is called when the garbage collector happens to be collecting the objects, not when you lose the last reference to an object and not when you execute `del object`.
- `__del__` is responsible for calling any `__del__` in a superclass, though it is not clear if this is in method resolution order (MRO) or just calling each superclass.
- Having a `__del__` means that the garbage collector gives up on detecting and cleaning any cyclic links, such as losing the last reference to a linked list. You can get a list of the objects ignored from gc.garbage. You can sometimes use weak references to avoid the cycle altogether. This gets debated now and then: see http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2009-October/006194.html.
- The `__del__` function can cheat, saving a reference to an object, and stopping the garbage collection.
- Exceptions explicitly raised in `__del__` are ignored.
- `__del__` complements `__new__` far more than `__init__`. This gets confusing. See [http://www.algorithm.co.il/blogs/programming/python-gotchas-1-**del**-is-not-the-opposite-of-**init**/](http://www.algorithm.co.il/blogs/programming/python-gotchas-1-__del__-is-not-the-opposite-of-__init__/) for an explanation and gotchas.
- `__del__` is not a "well-loved" child in Python. You will notice that sys.exit() documentation does not specify if garbage is collected before exiting, and there are lots of odd issues. Calling the `__del__` on globals causes odd ordering issues, e.g., http://bugs.python.org/issue5099. Should `__del__` called even if the `__init__` fails? See http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2000-March/thread.html#2423 for a long thread.

But, on the other hand:

- `__del__` means you do not forget to call a close statement. See http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python/ for a pro `__del__` viewpoint. This is usually about freeing ctypes or some other special resource.

And my pesonal reason for not liking the `__del__` function.

- Everytime someone brings up `__del__` it devolves into thirty messages of confusion.
- It breaks these items in the Zen of Python:

  - Simple is better than complicated.
  - Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
  - Errors should never pass silently.
  - In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
  - There should be one – and preferably only one – obvious way to do it.
  - If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.

So, find a reason not to use `__del__`.

Comment: Even if the question is not exactly: why should we not use `__del__`, but how to call `__del__`, your answer is interesting.

Comment: In other news, I forgot to mention that PyPy (a faster interpreter for longer running apps) will break on __del__.

Comment: @CharlesMerriam Thank _you_ for the answer!

Comment: You have mentioned "__del__ is called when the garbage collector happens to be collecting the objects, not when you lose the last reference to an object". However, the documentation clearly states that: "Note: del x doesn’t directly call x.__del__() — the former decrements the reference count for x by one, and the latter is only called when x’s reference count reaches zero". So __del__ is always called when you lose the last reference to the object.

Comment: It's a bit more random than that I'm afraid.   There are many reasons for not losing the last reference, and many are transient which makes reasoning and debugging difficult.  And there are differences in implementations,  and there are hard stops, and.. and... and...   Try to recognized the ravenous bugblatter beast and use the towel to avoid it.

Comment: '__del__ is responsible for calling any __del__ in a superclass, though it is not clear if this is in method resolution order (MRO) or just calling each superclass.': probably it needs to do a call to super() and if all base classes do the same, the whole mro is covered.

Comment: Once you write a *del* operation, you are switching away automatic transmission of messages to superclasses.  This means you are responsible for deciding the MRO, with the consequent grinding for special operations.  This is manual, or 'driving stick'.

Answer (score 20):

The `__del__` method, it will be called when the object is garbage collected.  Note that it isn't necessarily guaranteed to be called though.  The following code by itself won't necessarily do it:

```
del obj
```

The reason being that `del` just decrements the reference count by one.  If something else has a reference to the object, `__del__` won't get called.

There are a few caveats to using `__del__` though.  Generally, they usually just aren't very useful.  It sounds to me more like you want to use a close method or maybe a [with statement](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111211102/http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

See the [python documentation on `__del__` methods](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__).

One other thing to note:  `__del__` methods can inhibit garbage collection if overused.  In particular, a circular reference that has more than one object with a `__del__` method won't get garbage collected.  This is because the garbage collector doesn't know which one to call first.  See the documentation on the [gc module](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.garbage) for more info.

Comment: As of Python 3.4, [PEP 442](https://peps.python.org/pep-0442/) has been implemented such that objects with a \_\_del\_\_ method can be garbage collected.

Answer (score 14):

The `__del__` method (note spelling!) is called when your object is finally destroyed.  Technically speaking (in cPython) that is when there are no more references to your object, ie when it goes out of scope.

If you want to delete your object and thus call the `__del__` method use

```
del obj1
```

which will delete the object (provided there weren't any other references to it).

I suggest you write a small class like this

```
class T:
    def __del__(self):
        print "deleted"
```

And investigate in the python interpreter, eg

```
>>> a = T()
>>> del a
deleted
>>> a = T()
>>> b = a
>>> del b
>>> del a
deleted
>>> def fn():
...     a = T()
...     print "exiting fn"
...
>>> fn()
exiting fn
deleted
>>>
```

Note that jython and ironpython have different rules as to exactly when the object is deleted and `__del__` is called.  It isn't considered good practice to use `__del__` though because of this and the fact that the object and its environment may be in an unknown state when it is called.  It isn't absolutely guaranteed `__del__` will be called either - the interpreter can exit in various ways without deleteting all objects.

Comment: compared with http://stackoverflow.com/a/2452895/611007 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1481512/611007 , `use del obj1` seems like a bad idea to rely on.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned earlier, the `__del__` functionality is somewhat unreliable. In cases where it might seem useful, consider using the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods instead. This will give a behaviour similar to the `with open() as f: pass` syntax used for accessing files. `__enter__` is automatically called when entering the scope of `with`, while `__exit__` is automatically called when exiting it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984325/explaining-pythons-enter-and-exit) for more details.