# Explaining Python's '__enter__' and '__exit__'

Tags: python, oop, with-statement, contextmanager

I saw this in someone's code. What does it mean?

```
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        self.stream.close()
```

Here is the complete code.

```
from __future__ import with_statement#for python2.5 

class a(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print 'sss'
        return 'sss111'
    def __exit__(self ,type, value, traceback):
        print 'ok'
        return False

with a() as s:
    print s
    
    
print s
```

Answer (score 654, accepted):

Using these magic methods (`__enter__`, `__exit__`) allows you to implement objects which can be used easily with the `with` statement.

The idea is that it makes it easy to build code which needs some 'cleandown' code executed (think of it as a `try-finally` block). [Some more explanation here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160427130542/http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

A useful example could be a database connection object (which then automagically closes the connection once the corresponding 'with'-statement goes out of scope):

```
class DatabaseConnection(object):

    def __enter__(self):
        # make a database connection and return it
        ...
        return self.dbconn

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        # make sure the dbconnection gets closed
        self.dbconn.close()
        ...
```

As explained above, use this object with the `with` statement (you may need to do `from __future__ import with_statement` at the top of the file if you're on Python 2.5).

```
with DatabaseConnection() as mydbconn:
    # do stuff
```

[PEP343 -- The 'with' statement'](https://peps.python.org/pep-0343/) has a nice writeup as well.

Comment: Probably, `__enter__` should return `self` always as then only other methods of the class can be called on the context.

Comment: @ViFI There are 4 examples of `def __enter__(self)` in PEP 343 and no one does `return self`: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/ . Why do you think so?

Comment: @Grief : For 2 reasons, In my opinion, 
1) i won't be able to call other methods on `self` object as explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281853/should-the-return-value-for-enter-method-always-be-self-in-python
2) self.XYZ is just part of self object and returning handle only to just that seems inappropriate to me from maintenance point of view. I would rather prefer to return handle to complete object and then provide public APIs to only those components `self` object,which I want to expose to user like in

`with open(abc.txt, 'r') as fin:
         content = fin.read()`

Comment: File objects return `self` from `__enter__`, which is how come you can process the file as `f` inside `with open(...) as f`

Comment: One subtlety I had to understand: if the object requires parameters to initialize, those should be on __init__, not __self__.

Comment: There are a ton of use cases to not return `self` and in any case that you do need the context object itself, you can always instantiate the context on line before the `with inst`.

Comment: IMO what is returned with `__enter__` should be up to the developer(s) of the class as long as the documented usage seems logical to the user(s) of the class:

1. Open a resource that is not meant to stay open

2. Use the resource, call certain methods on the resource, etc

3. The resource is closed

Comment: link is broken for effbot

Answer (score 140):

If you know what **context managers** are then you need nothing more to understand `__enter__` and `__exit__` magic methods. Lets see a very simple example.

In this example I am opening the **myfile.txt** file with help of **open** function. The **try/finally** block ensures that even if an unexpected exception occurs **myfile.txt** will be closed.

```
fp=open(r"C:\Users\SharpEl\Desktop\myfile.txt")
try:
    for line in fp:
        print(line)
finally:
    fp.close()
```

Now I am opening same file with **with** statement:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\SharpEl\Desktop\myfile.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print(line)
```

If you look at the code, I  didn't close the file & there is no **try/finally** block. Because **with** statement automatically closes  **myfile.txt** . You can even check it by calling `print(fp.closed)` attribute -- which returns `True`.

This is because the file objects (fp in my example) returned by **open** function has two built-in methods `__enter__` and `__exit__`. It is  also known as context manager. `__enter__` method is called at the start of **with** block and `__exit__`  method is called at the end.

Note: **with** statement only works with objects that support the context management protocol (i.e. they have `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods). A class which implement both methods is known as context manager class.

Now lets define our own **context manager** class.

```
 class Log:
    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.filename=filename
        self.fp=None    
    def logging(self,text):
        self.fp.write(text+'\n')
    def __enter__(self):
        print("__enter__")
        self.fp=open(self.filename,"a+")
        return self    
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print("__exit__")
        self.fp.close()

with Log(r"C:\Users\SharpEl\Desktop\myfile.txt") as logfile:
    print("Main")
    logfile.logging("Test1")
    logfile.logging("Test2")
```

I hope now you have basic understanding of both `__enter__` and `__exit__` magic methods.

Answer (score 100):

I found it strangely difficult to locate the python docs for `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods by Googling, so to help others here is the link:

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers
(detail is the same for both versions)

> `object.__enter__(self)`
> Enter the runtime context related to this object. The `with` statement will bind this method’s return value to the target(s) specified in the as clause of the statement, if any.

> `object.__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)`
> Exit the runtime context related to this object. The parameters describe the exception that caused the context to be exited. If the context was exited without an exception, all three arguments will be `None`.

> If an exception is supplied, and the method wishes to suppress the exception (i.e., prevent it from being propagated), it should return a true value. Otherwise, the exception will be processed normally upon exit from this method.

> Note that `__exit__()` methods should not reraise the passed-in exception; this is the caller’s responsibility.

I was hoping for a clear description of the `__exit__` method arguments. This is lacking but we can deduce them...

Presumably `exc_type` is the class of the exception.

It says you should not re-raise the passed-in exception. This suggests to us that one of the arguments might be an actual Exception instance ...or maybe you're supposed to instantiate it yourself from the type and value?

We can answer by looking at this article:
[http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111211102/http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)

> For example, the following `__exit__` method swallows any TypeError, but lets all other exceptions through:

```
def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    return isinstance(value, TypeError)
```

...so clearly `value` is an Exception instance.

And presumably `traceback` is a Python [traceback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) object.

Note that there are further docs here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types

...they have a slightly more detailed explanation of the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. Particularly it is more explicit that `__exit__` should return a boolean value (though truthy or falsy will work fine, e.g. an implicit `None` return will give the default behaviour of propagating the exception).

Comment: might be important to note this buried bit within the PEP reference noting the arg use:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/#generator-decorator

Comment: FWIW, the \`__exit__` method args seem to be the output tuple of [sys.exc_info()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info)

Answer (score 98):

In addition to the above answers to exemplify invocation order, a simple run example

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("__init__")

    def __enter__(self): 
        print("__enter__")

    def __exit__(self, ex_type, ex_value, ex_traceback):
        print("__exit__")
    
    def __del__(self):
        print("__del__")
    
with MyClass(): 
    print("body")
```

Produces the output:

```
__init__
__enter__
body
__exit__
__del__
```

A reminder: when using the syntax `with MyClass() as my_handler`, variable my_handler gets the value returned by `__enter__()`, in the above case `None`! For such use, need to define return value, such as:

```py
def __enter__(self): 
    print('__enter__')
    return self
```

Comment: And even if the sequence of the definitions are switched, the executing order stays the same!

Comment: When an `as` clause is used (`with MyClass() as my_handler`), there is no more `__del__` in the output…

Answer (score 8):

try adding my answers (my thought of learning) :

`__enter__` and `[__exit__]` both are methods that are invoked on entry to and exit from the body of "**the with statement**" ([PEP 343](https://peps.python.org/pep-0343/)) and implementation of both is called context manager.

the with statement is intend to hiding flow control of try finally clause and make the code inscrutable.

the syntax of the with statement is :

```
with EXPR as VAR:
    BLOCK
```

which translate to (as mention in PEP 343) :

```
mgr = (EXPR)
exit = type(mgr).__exit__  # Not calling it yet
value = type(mgr).__enter__(mgr)
exc = True
try:
    try:
        VAR = value  # Only if "as VAR" is present
        BLOCK
    except:
        # The exceptional case is handled here
        exc = False
        if not exit(mgr, *sys.exc_info()):
            raise
        # The exception is swallowed if exit() returns true
finally:
    # The normal and non-local-goto cases are handled here
    if exc:
        exit(mgr, None, None, None)
```

try some code:

```
>>> import logging
>>> import socket
>>> import sys

#server socket on another terminal / python interpreter
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> s.listen(5)
>>> s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 999))
>>> while True:
>>>    (clientsocket, addr) = s.accept()
>>>    print('get connection from %r' % addr[0])
>>>    msg = clientsocket.recv(1024)
>>>    print('received %r' % msg)
>>>    clientsocket.send(b'connected')
>>>    continue

#the client side
>>> class MyConnectionManager:
>>>     def __init__(self, sock, addrs):
>>>         logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s \
>>>         : %(levelname)s --> %(message)s')
>>>         logging.info('Initiating My connection')
>>>         self.sock = sock
>>>         self.addrs = addrs
>>>     def __enter__(self):
>>>         try:
>>>             self.sock.connect(addrs)
>>>             logging.info('connection success')
>>>             return self.sock
>>>         except:
>>>             logging.warning('Connection refused')
>>>             raise
>>>     def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
>>>             logging.info('CM suppress exception')
>>>             return False
>>> addrs = (socket.gethostname())
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> with MyConnectionManager(s, addrs) as CM:
>>>     try:
>>>         CM.send(b'establishing connection')
>>>         msg = CM.recv(1024)
>>>         print(msg)
>>>     except:
>>>         raise
#will result (client side) :
2018-12-18 14:44:05,863         : INFO --> Initiating My connection
2018-12-18 14:44:05,863         : INFO --> connection success
b'connected'
2018-12-18 14:44:05,864         : INFO --> CM suppress exception

#result of server side
get connection from '127.0.0.1'
received b'establishing connection'
```

and now try manually (following translate syntax):

```
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #make new socket object
>>> mgr = MyConnection(s, addrs)
2018-12-18 14:53:19,331         : INFO --> Initiating My connection
>>> ext = mgr.__exit__
>>> value = mgr.__enter__()
2018-12-18 14:55:55,491         : INFO --> connection success
>>> exc = True
>>> try:
>>>     try:
>>>         VAR = value
>>>         VAR.send(b'establishing connection')
>>>         msg = VAR.recv(1024)
>>>         print(msg)
>>>     except:
>>>         exc = False
>>>         if not ext(*sys.exc_info()):
>>>             raise
>>> finally:
>>>     if exc:
>>>         ext(None, None, None)
#the result:
b'connected'
2018-12-18 15:01:54,208         : INFO --> CM suppress exception
```

the result of the server side same as before

sorry for my bad english and my unclear explanations, thank you....

Answer (score 7):

This is called context manager and I just want to add that similar approaches exist for other programming languages. Comparing them could be helpful in understanding the context manager in python.
Basically, a context manager is used when we are dealing with some resources (file, network, database) that need to be initialized and at some point, tear downed (disposed). In **Java 7** and above we have automatic resource management that takes the form of:

```
//Java code
try (Session session = new Session())
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Note that Session needs to implement `AutoClosable` or one of its (many) sub-interfaces.

In **C#**, we have using statements for managing resources that takes the form of:

```
//C# code
using(Session session = new Session())
{
  ... do stuff.
}
```

In which `Session` should implement `IDisposable`.

In **python**, the class that we use should implement `__enter__` and `__exit__`. So it takes the form of:

```
#Python code
with Session() as session:
    #do stuff
```

And as others pointed out, you can always use try/finally statement in all the languages to implement the same mechanism. This is just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 2):

Python calls `__enter__` when execution enters the context of the with statement and it’s time to acquire the resource. When execution leaves the context again, Python calls `__exit__` to free up the resource

Let's consider Context Managers and the “with” Statement in Python. Context Manager is a simple “protocol” (or interface) that your object needs to follow so it can be used with the with statement. Basically all you need to do is add **enter** and **exit** methods to an object if you want it to function as a context manager. Python will call these two methods at the appropriate times in the resource management cycle.

Let’s take a look at what this would look like in practical terms. Here’s how a simple implementation of the open() context manager might look like:

```
class ManagedFile:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        self.file = open(self.name, 'w')
        return self.file

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.file:
            self.file.close()
```

Our ManagedFile class follows the context manager protocol and now supports the with statement.

```
>>> with ManagedFile('hello.txt') as f:
...    f.write('hello, world!')
...    f.write('bye now')`enter code here`
```

Python calls **enter** when execution enters the context of the with statement and it’s time to acquire the resource. When execution leaves the context again, Python calls **exit** to free up the resource.

Writing a class-based context manager isn’t the only way to support the with statement in Python. The contextlib utility module in the standard library provides a few more abstractions built on top of the basic context manager protocol. This can make your life a little easier if your use cases matches what’s offered by contextlib.