# How to simplify this kind of Python code?

Tags: python

I have many blocks of code like this:

```
try:
  a = get_a()
  try:
    b = get_b()

    # varying codes here, where a and b are used

  finally:
    if b:
      cleanup(b)
finally:
  if a:
    cleanup(a)
```

I hope to write some magic code like this:

```
some_magic:
  # varying codes here, where a and b are also available
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not merge them both inside a single `try` and `finally`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't or don't want to implement context protocol for `a` and `b`, you can use [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) facilities to make a context:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def managed(a):
    try:
        yield a
    finally:
        if a:
            cleanup(a)

with managed(get_a()) as a, managed(get_b()) as b:
    # do something here
    pass
```

Comment: upvoted (was about to write that after hunting references)

Answer (score 3):

Let classes of `a` and `b` implement the context manager protocol, and use the [`with` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for):

```
with get_a() as a, get_b() as b:
    do_magic
```

Now if `get_a` and `get_b` returned open file handles, they'd be automatically closed at the end of the block. If the values returned are of a custom class, that class should have the [`__enter__` and `__exit__` magic methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984325/explaining-pythons-enter-and-exit).