# should the return value for `__enter__` method always be `self` in python

Tags: python

Shouldn't the return value for the `__enter__` method be `self` always.

[Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) says :

> `object.__enter__(self)`
>   Enter the runtime context related to this
>   object. The with statement will bind this method’s return value to the
>   target(s) specified in the as clause of the statement, if any.

With this, to do anything practical, should't `self` be returned always from `__enter__` method of a class as without it one would not be able to call other class methods on the context.

For example, in the following code, s.main() works fine but b1.main() errors out.

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self ,type, value, traceback):
        return self

    def main(self):
        print " in a::main self %d " , id(self)


class b(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        return "something else"

    def __exit__(self ,type, value, traceback):
        pass

    def main(self):
        print "in b::main !! self id " , id(self)

with a() as s:
    s.main()

with b() as b1:
    b1.main()

s = a()
s.main()
```

Comment: The question boils down to "can you imagine a case, where it would be practical to return something other than `self` from `__enter__`". And, well, that depends on your fantasy.

Comment: Definitely not always:

https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/4856493efc1f6b7fdecf36e020a95636f600a626/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py#L1925

Comment: I think anyone interested in this question might also benefit from MisterMiyagi's more detailed answer on [my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60561959/is-returning-a-value-other-than-self-in-enter-an-anti-pattern/60563726#60563726)

Comment: [Another example is `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory` in the standard library.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory)

Answer (score 4):

Not if it makes sense to use an attribute of the instance as the context manager:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, useful_obj):
        self.useful_obj = useful_obj

   def __enter__(self):
       return self.useful_obj

   def __exit__(self):
       pass

with A(some_obj) as a:
    # magic done implicitly by a.useful_obj
    .
    .
    .
```

This situation can be seen in SqlAlchemy's [code](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/4856493efc1f6b7fdecf36e020a95636f600a626/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py#L1925).

The code sample that you provided would work if you use any of the `str` methods, for example:

```
with b() as b1:
    print b1.upper()

>> SOMETHING ELSE
```