# Is returning a value other than `self` in `__enter__` an anti-pattern?

Tags: python

Following [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281853/should-the-return-value-for-enter-method-always-be-self-in-python),  while there are always examples of some library using a language feature in a unique way, I was wondering whether returning a value other than `self` in an `__enter__` method should be considered an anti-pattern.

The main reason why this seems to me like a bad idea is that it makes wrapping context managers problematic. For example, in Java (also possible in C#), one can wrap an `AutoCloseable` class in another  class which will take care of cleaning up after the inner class, like in the following code snippet:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = 
     new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/main/resources/input.txt"))) {
  return readAllLines(reader);
}
```

Here, `BufferedReader` wraps `FileReader`, and calls `FileReader`'s `close()` method inside its own `close()` method. However, if this was Python, and `FileReader` would've returned an object other than self in its `__enter__` method, this would make such an arrangement significantly more complicated. The following issues would have to be addressed by the writer of `BufferedReader`:

1. When I need to use `FileReader` for my own methods, do I use `FileReader` directly or the object returned by its `__enter__` method? What methods are even supported by the returned object?
2. In my `__exit__` method, do I need to close only the `FileReader` object, or the object returned in the `__enter__` method?
3. What happens if `__enter__` actually returns a different object on its call? Do I now need to keep a collection of all of the different objects returned by it in case someone calls `__enter__` several times on me? How do I know which one to use when I need to use on of these objects?

And the list goes on. One semi-successful solution to all of these problems would be to simply avoid having one context manager class clean up after another context manager class. In my example, that would mean that we would need two nested `with` blocks - one for the `FileReader`, and one for the `BufferedReader`. However, this makes us write more boilerplate code, and seems significantly less elegant.

All in all, these issues lead me to believe that while Python does allow us to return something other than `self` in the `__enter__` method, this behavior should simply be avoided. Is there some official or semi-official remarks about these issues? How should a responsible Python developer write code that addresses these issues?

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed as opinion based, since the last paragraph has pretty concrete questions that can be answered relatively objectively. In general, all good code practices can be considered opinion-based, but I think questions about them are appropriate.

Comment: Please clarify your question to allow for a clear, objective answer. Returning things other than ``self`` is not uncommon, and the standard library has several examples. Your code example does not match how context managers are used in Python, and the same situation Python would have no problem identifying the respective objects. Whether to use an object or one returned by its methods is a general question and not related to context managers at all. The protocol makes it clear which ones to use for ``__enter__`` and ``__exit__``. Also, various helpers like ``contextlib.ExitStack`` exist.

Comment: You can return anything. In `__exit__` you just need to clean up after yourself, no matter what you returned. And yes, in most cases you return `self` or other simple thing, because that's the most logical thing to do - it all depends on your object's logic.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Your comment can actually be a perfectly good answer to my question if you wrote it in more detail, and I would highly appreciate it if you did so.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi My reasoning is opinion based, but is only meant to explain the need for my question. My question, however, is about the general case. If you can explain in detail why the Java example doesn't translate well to Python, and how context managers should be used in Python instead, it would be a perfect answer. My question comes from a place of a developer who has experience in Java, but not in Python.

Comment: I am very disappointed that this question was closed without any reasoning, and despite the fact that is is already answered with a great and very educating answer.

Comment: It is reopened now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR: Returning something other than `self` from `__enter__` is perfectly fine and not bad practice.

The [introducing PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343) and [Context Manager specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types) expressly list this as desired use cases.

> An example of a context manager that returns a related object is the
>   one returned by `decimal.localcontext()`. These managers set the active
>   decimal context to a copy of the original decimal context and then
>   return the copy. This allows changes to be made to the current decimal
>   context in the body of the `with` statement without affecting code
>   outside the `with` statement.

---

The standard library has several examples of returning something other than `self` from `__enter__`. Notably, much of `contextlib` matches this pattern.

- [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) produces context managers which cannot return `self`, because there is no such thing.
- [`contextlib.closing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) wraps a `thing` and returns it on `__enter__`.
- [`contextlib.nullcontext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nullcontext) returns a pre-defined constant
- [`threading.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) returns a boolean
- [`decimal.localcontext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.localcontext) returns a copy of its argument

---

The context manager protocol makes it clear what is the context manager, and who is responsible for cleanup. Most importantly, **the return value of `__enter__` is inconsequential for the protocol**.

A rough paraphrasing of the protocol is this: **When something runs `cm.__enter__`, it is responsible for running `cm.__exit__`.** Notably, whatever code does that has access to `cm` (the context manager itself); the result of `cm.__enter__` is not needed to call `cm.__exit__`.

In other words, a code that takes (and runs) a `ContextManager` must run it completely. Any other code does not have to care whether its value comes from a `ContextManager` or not.

```
# entering a context manager requires closing it…
def managing(cm: ContextManager):
    value = cm.__enter__()  # must clean up `cm` after this point
    try:
        yield from unmanaged(value)
    except BaseException as exc:
        if not cm.__exit__(type(exc), exc, exc.__traceback__):
           raise
    else:
        cm.__exit__(None, None, None)

# …other code does not need to know where its values come from
def unmanaged(smth: Any):
    yield smth
```

When context managers wrap others, the same rules apply: If the outer context manager calls the inner one's `__enter__`, it must call its `__exit__` as well. If the outer context manager already has the entered inner context manager, it is not responsible for cleanup.

---

In some cases it is in fact bad practice to return `self` from `__enter__`. Returning `self` from `__enter__` should only be done if `self` is fully initialised beforehand; if `__enter__` runs any initialisation code, a separate object should be returned.

```
class BadContextManager:
      """
      Anti Pattern: Context manager is in inconsistent state before ``__enter__``
      """
      def __init__(self, path):
          self.path = path
          self._file = None  # BAD: initialisation not complete

      def read(self, n: int):
          return self._file.read(n)  # fails before the context is entered!

      def __enter__(self) -> 'BadContextManager':
          self._file = open(self.path)
          return self  # BAD: self was not valid before

      def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, tb):
          self._file.close()

class GoodContext:
      def __init__(self, path):
          self.path = path
          self._file = None  # GOOD: Inconsistent state not visible/used

      def __enter__(self) -> TextIO:
          if self._file is not None:
             raise RuntimeError(f'{self.__class__.__name__} is not re-entrant')
          self._file = open(self.path)
          return self._file  # GOOD: value was not accessible before

      def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, tb):
          self._file.close()
```

Notably, even though `GoodContext` returns a different object, it is still responsible to clean up. Another context manager wrapping `GoodContext` does not need to close the return value, it just has to call `GoodContext.__exit__`.

Comment: contextlib.ExitStack also very specifically supports (if not outright encourages) this use-case.

Comment: I know comments shouldn't be used for "thank you's", but I want to emphasize that I think this is an outstanding answer which I keep coming back to and referring others to. It explains a non-trivial topic which confuses many people very well