# How to modify the object of a class-based context manager?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, with-statement

I would like, within the `with` scope, to modify the object of the context manager. Consider the followig code:

```
class CM:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def __enter__(self):
        self.a = 2
        return self.a

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print(self.a)


with CM() as a:
    a = 3
```

I wanted in the `with` scope assign `3` to `self.a` (and therefore see an output of `3`). The code outputs `2`, the value of `self.a` in the class.

**Is it possible to modify it outside of the class?** (an analogy would be to modify an object property)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is returning a value other than `self` in `__enter__` an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60561959/is-returning-a-value-other-than-self-in-enter-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Found it, I need to return the object itself:

```
class CM:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def __enter__(self):
        self.a = 2
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print(self.a)


with CM() as a:
    a.a = 3
```