# Subclassed object results in NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, subclass

I'm trying to subclass the Chrome WebDriver to include some initialization and cleanup code, but then Python complains that the created object is set to `None`:

```
import glob
import selenium
import subprocess
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class WebDriver(selenium.webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, url, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.url = url

    def __enter__(self):
        self.get(self.url)
        self.implicitly_wait(15)

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.quit()
        for path in glob.glob('/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.*'):
            subprocess.run(['rm', '-rf', path], check=True)


with WebDriver('https://google.com') as driver:
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'lst-ib').send_keys('Search')
```

Running the code with Python 3:

```
$ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 43, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'lst-ib').send_keys('Search')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `__enter__()` magic method should return `self` for the `driver` variable to be pointed to the instance of the `WebDriver` class:

```
def __enter__(self):
    self.get(self.url)
    self.implicitly_wait(15)
    return self
```

To get more information about why and how this works, please see:

- [Understanding Python's "with" statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)
- [Explaining Python's '__enter__' and '__exit__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984325/explaining-pythons-enter-and-exit)