# Closing a connection with a `with` statement

Tags: python, imap, with-statement, imaplib

I want to have a class that represents an IMAP connection and use it with a `with` statement as follows:

```
class IMAPConnection:
    def __enter__(self):
        connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP_HOST)

        try:
            connection.login(MAIL_USERNAME, MAIL_PASS)
        except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
            log.error('Failed to log in')

        return connection

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.close()

with IMAPConnection() as c:
    rv, data = c.list()
    print(rv, data)
```

Naturally this fails since `IMAPConnections` has no attribute `close`. How can I store the connection and pass it to the `__exit__` function when the `with` statement is finished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store connection in object attributes. Something like this:

```
class IMAPConnection:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP_HOST)

        try:
            self.connection.login(MAIL_USERNAME, MAIL_PASS)
        except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
            log.error('Failed to log in')

        return self.connection

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.connection.close()
```

You would also want to implement `list` method for you class.

Edit: I just now realized what your actual problem is. when you do `with SomeClass(*args, **kwargs) as c` `c` is not a value returned by `__enter__` method. `c` is instance of `SomeClass`. That's a root of your problem you returned connection from `__enter__` and assumed that `c` is said connection.

Comment: Ha, gotcha. Thanks!

Comment: I added some more explanation in my answer. Hope it's helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a `__exit__()` function within your `IMAPConnection` class.

`__enter__()` function is called before executing the code within the `with` block where as `__exit__()` is called while exiting the `with` block.

Below is the sample structure:

```
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    # Close the connection and other logic applicable
    self.connection.close()
```

Check: [Explaining Python's '**enter**' and '**exit**'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1984346/2063361) for more information.