# Should I manually close a database connection if using context managing (with-as)?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm learning how to use a PostgreSQL database with Python (3.6)'s psycopg2 module. I'm having trouble figuring out exactly under which circumstances I should manually close my connections.
According to [the docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#transactions-control):

> unlike file objects or other resources, exiting the connection’s with
>   block doesn’t close the connection but only the transaction associated
>   with it: a connection can be used in more than a with statement and
>   each with block is effectively wrapped in a separate transaction

But then comes an example code snippet:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)

with conn:
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        curs.execute(SQL1)

with conn:
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        curs.execute(SQL2)

conn.close()
```

However, I'm used to seeing context managing using with-as, i.e. something like

```
with psycopg2.connect(DSN) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        curs.execute(SQL)
```

Is this a reasonable approach, or will there still be an open connection after running the above? If so, how do I close it, since 'conn' no longer exists?

Comment: a) Yes, to prevent creating an idle connection every time this code is called. Consider if this code was inside a function and that function was called hundreds of times. b) Also, if this code triggers an exception the connection is not closed, it becomes idle. If you get hundreds of idle connections, eventually the server crashes. So do not rely on gc to patch code that might leak a connection; close it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to official doc: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.close

> Close the connection now (rather than whenever del is executed)....

When a `connection` object is deleted, it will be closed. Although I didn't find related source code as they are all written in C++.

Comment: "When a connection object is deleted, it will be closed"
- meaning including when you de-indent from a with-as block, then?

Comment: Yes. `conn` object loses all references and will be deleted by GC.

Comment: Thanks. Immediately, or after some period? I have a limit to how many connections my database accepts at a time, so that makes a difference and I'm not knowledgeable about how the GC works.

Comment: It all depends on GC's mood... Not kidding, but serious. Generally GC will almost immediately collect unused objects. But we cannot directly control it at all.

Comment: Okay, so it might be a good idea to close the connection inside the with-block just in case?

Comment: Yeah, that's true.

Comment: So it means one can skip `conn.close()` if conn is no longer referenced?

Comment: The whole point of using a context manager is that it will do the cleanup for you automatically. Except under extreme circumstances, there's no need to even think about closing connections.

Comment: This advice is dangerous (in general, a connection is *not* guaranteed to be removed until it is deleted or (*whenever*) GC happens to get run, meantime a pool could leak connections, maybe for weeks); also misleadingly broad: just because psycopg2 implemented it right, don't assume that all MySQL and other wrappers do it the right way; there are tons of questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57775507/using-a-context-manager-with-mysql-connector-python), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41534568/mysql-connector-python-not-closing-connection-explicitly) etc.

Comment: The question title is the very broad "database connection... context manager"; if answers are intended only for Postgres with psycopg2, then you should say so clearly at the top of the answer, or edit the question title. It's still dangerously general advice for everyone using other packages or DBs.