# Using a context manager with mysql connector python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, contextmanager

I'm moving my code across from an sqlite database to mysql and I'm having a problem with the context manager, getting the following attribute error.

I've tried combinations of mydb.cursor() as cursor, mydb: etc...

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
    database="database_name"

cur = mydb.cursor()
```

```
with mydb as cursor:
 AttributeError: __enter__
```

Answer (score 12):

Python has a built-in way to implement a context manager if the object you're creating have a `.close()` method, by using the `contextlib.closing` context manager.

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing):

> #### contextlib.closing(*thing*)
>
> Return a context manager that closes *thing* upon completion of the block.
> This is basically equivalent to:
>
> ```
>  from contextlib import contextmanager
>  
>  @contextmanager
>  def closing(thing):
>      try:
>          yield thing
>      finally:
>          thing.close()
> ```

So, for your specific issue, you can use not only on the connection, but also the cursor.

Your code would be:

```py
from contextlib import closing

import mysql.connector


query = "SELECT * FROM table"

db_conn_info = {
    "user": "root",
    "passwd": "",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5000,
    "database": "database_name"
}

with closing(mysql.connector.connect(**db_conn_info)) as conn:
    with closing(conn.cursor()) as cur:
        cur.execute(query)
        result = cur.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to define your own context manager as `mysql.connector.connect` is not a context manager.
Context managers have to be defined with `__enter__` and `__exit__` attributes.
It should be something like this. (Tested using `psycopg2`)

```py
class DBConnection:

    def __init__(self):
        self.mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            passwd="",
            database="database_name"
        )
        self.cur = self.mydb.cursor()
   
   def __enter__(self):
        return self

   def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        # close db connection
        self.mydb.connection.close()
```