# How to use a TensorFlow session as a class attribute

Tags: class, session, tensorflow

I am using a session as an attribute of my class, as in

```
self.sess = tf.Session()
```

or

```
self.sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
```

The session attribute is used in several functions, e.g.

```
def get_loss(self, input_data):
        return self.sess.run(self.loss, {self.data:input_data})
```

I know that a session has to be closed at some point. Does this also apply when using the session as an attribute of a class? Do I need a "close_session" function somewhere? If yes, where exactly should I put it in the class?

Regrettably, I couldn't find anything on sessions as class attributes so I am thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement a `close()` or `__exit__()` member function that calls `self.sess.close()`. Then use your object as you would do with a `Session`:

```
with MyClass() as myobj:
    ...
```

EDIT (increased verbosity level)

Regarding python's `with` statement, its usefulness and how to build compatible classes, there are [plenty](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) [of](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/) [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984325/explaining-pythons-enter-and-exit) [out there](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/). Its use is basically to neatly handle the life cycle of the resources of an object.

A clean way to use a context manager (an object usually handled with a `with` statement) as a member function of a class is to make that class a context manager itself.

If you simply open a `Session` context within a member function of your object, then the effective lifespan of this object (of its resources anyway) ends with the `with` block: in effect, this session object is not a class member but simply a local variable of the function. If you want to use the same `Session` in several member functions of your class, you need to extend the lifetime of the `Session` resources beyond a single function and let the resources be handles by your class by letting it be a context manager.

Comment: At what time should I call the sess.close() function?

Comment: `Session.close()` is be called when `MyClass.close()` is called, and if you follow the idiom above, that will be called when the `with` scope is closed. In short, do not call them by hand but let scopes take care of it.

Comment: Sorry but I'm still not sure whether I understand what you mean. When I initialize an instance of the class, like instance = MyClass(params) how should I use it with a with scope? And how is MyClass.close() automatically called in your with scope? Could you maybe provide a link showing this construction in practice?

Comment: Wouldn't it rather make sense to use "with instance.session as sess:" after initializing a member of the class? Also, I would have to change all my functions in the class, correct? Right now, as shown in the original post, a class returns e.g. "self.sess.run(self.loss, ...)"