# Call __exit__ on all members of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a Pythonic way to automatically `__exit__` all members of a class?

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = open('foo')
        self.b = open('bar')

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        # Is it correct to just forward the parameters here?
        self.a.__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
        self.b.__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
```

Can I do this without manually calling `__exit__` on `a` and `b`? Am I even calling `__exit__` correctly?

Suppose that the resources I have aren't `file`s like in the example and there isn't a method like `close` or `destroy`. Is it perhaps good practice to implement a method like this on top of the `__enter__` and `__exit__`?

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1984346/3129414)?

Comment: @arsho Yes, I have.

Comment: I think most helpfull here will be : `contextlib.ExitStack`

Comment: @Take_Care_ Hey, this seems perfect! Could you expand your comment into a whole answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Or in python-3.7 you can use [contextlib.AsyncExitStack](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.AsyncExitStack)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as I mentioned in comment :

> I think most helpfull here will be : `contextlib.ExitStack`

You can create this object as a member of Your own class in the `__init__`.
And then add to it all your depending contextmanagers with the `enter_context(cm)` where **cm** is context_manager

```
def __init__(self):
    self.exit_stack = contextlib.ExitStack()
    self.exit_stack.__enter__()
    self.exit_stack.enter_context(open('foo')) 
    ....
```

to clear all the depending contexts just call in the `__exit__` the exit of this stack.

**Or better just subclass `ExitStack` and in init call the `enter_context`.**

Answer (score 2):

Writing your own `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions tends to not be a great idea. You need to understand what should happen if an exception occurs during a child `__exit__` or what it means if `__exit__` returns a truthful value.

It's generally better just to write a generator-based context manager instead. eg.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

class A:
    def __init__(self, filename0, filename1, file0, file1):
        self.filename0 = filename0
        self.filename1 = filename1
        self.file0 = file0
        self.file1 = file1

    @classmethod
    @contextmanager
    def create(cls, filename0, filename1):
        with open(filename0) as file0, \
                open(filename1) as file1:
            yield cls(filename0, filename1, file0, file1)

with A.create('file0.txt', 'file1.txt') as a:
    a.do_something()
```

This will open the child context managers in defined order, and automatically close them in a defined order, propagating exceptions and return values correctly.

Comment: Given that `A.create` is a `classmethod` in your example, this really does not address the OP's question. What if there are multiple resources "open" for the entire lifetype of `A` (not just a call to one of its methods)?

Answer (score 0):

`__enter__` and `__exit__` special functions are almost never called manually. There are respectively called when entering and leaving a `with` block statement. So if you use something like:

```
with C() as c:
    # stuff
# other stuff
```

you call these magic functions. In you case, I would call the file `open` functions in `__enter__` and the corresponding `close` function in `__exit__`

For instance:

```
class C:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.a = open('foo')
        self.b = open('bar')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.a.close()
        self.b.close()

    def readline_a(self):
      return self.a.readline()

    def readline_b(self):
      return self.b.readline()

with C() as c:
  print(c.readline_a())
  print(c.readline_b())
```

prints the first line of each file `foo` and `bar`

Comment: If your resource only requires memory allocation, it is better to rely on the garbage collector to free the resource. In the other cases, I guess that there is always some kind of method that says "don't need this stuff anymore". Have you a precise example in mind?

Answer (score 0):

To provide context manager functionality for instance members, one might do something like this:

```
class MemberManager:
    managed_member_names = ('a', 'b', 'c')
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = a, b, c
    def __enter__(self):
        # yield statement means this enter method returns a generator
        for i in (getattr(self,n) for n self.managed_member_names):
            with open(i, mode="w") as x:
                # yield prevents the context manager from exiting
                yield x
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        # all items will be closed by __enter__ context manager; nothing needed here
        pass

mm = MemberManager(fname1, fname2, fname3)
with mm as open_members:
    # open_members is a generator/iterator
    for member in open_members:
        member.write("foo")
```

However, note that you cannot do this:

```
with mm as open_members:
    open_member_list = list(open_members)
    open_member_list[0].write("foo") # ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

The `open_members` iterator must remain unexhausted for the current file to remain open.