# Python Error: "AttributeError: __enter__"

Tags: python, json, enter

So, I can't load my json file and I don't know why, can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
async def give(msg, arg):
    if arg[0] == prefix + "dailycase":
                with open("commands/databases/cases.json", "r") as d:
                     data = json.load(d)
```

For some reason I'm getting this error:

```
    with open("commands/databases/cases.json", "r") as d:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Comment: Do you have the builtin `open` defined to something else in your code? Either by assignment (`open =`) or by importing it from somewhere (`from place import open`)?

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate, but is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984325/explaining-pythons-enter-and-exit

Comment: To test @LukasGraf 's theory: `print(open.__doc__)` ... if you don't see a massive blob of internal python text, starting with "Open file and return a stream", then his theory is correct.

Comment: @JacobIRR: You can confirm if it's the built-in `open` by just doing `import io`, and testing `open is io.open` (on Python 3, the built-in `open` aliases `io.open`).

Comment: @RyanHaining: Not necessarily; `__enter__` isn't looked up until the item in question is fully constructed; odds are the `open` call succeeded, it just referenced the wrong `open`, but once it succeeds, that wrong `open` isn't on the call stack anymore.

Comment: @ShadowRanger you're right. did not realize, removed comment

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Most likely, you have reassigned the Python [builtin `open` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) to something else in your code (*there's almost no other plausible way this exception could be explained*).

The `with` statement will then attempt to use it as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers), and will try to call its `__enter__` method when first entering the `with` block. This then leads to the error message you're seeing because your object called `open`, whatever it is, doesn't have an `__enter__` method.

---

Look for places in your Python module where you are re-assigning `open`. The most obvious ones are:

- A function in the global scope, like `def open(..)`
- Direct reassignment using `open =`
- Imports like `from foo import open` or `import something as open`

The **function** is the most likely suspect, because it seems your `open` is actually a callable.

To aid you finding what object `open` was accidentally bound to, you can also try to

```
print('open is assigned to %r' % open)
```

immediately before your `with` statement. If it doesn't say `<built-in function open>`, you've found your culprit.

Comment: I double checked all my file's script to see what I did wrong, and nope, I haven't ant variable or import named "open", but I did a mistake and I saw I created a function named "open" and I did not realize. Thank you for the support and sorry about that!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help - shadowing a builtin name is a gotcha that tripped up most of us at one time or another ;-)

Comment: Also check python version. OP's syntax is only supported in 3.8+
My solution below has the python 3.6 syntax.

Comment: Im also getting the same error on this basic code and have no clue why https://snippet.host/pbwp

Comment: @Grimeire `requests.get` is not a context manager, so you can't use it in a `with` statement. But `requests.Session()` is - that's probably what you meant to use. So you could do `with requests.Session() as session: r = session.get(dl_link, stream=True, headers=headers)`

Comment: I found out after commenting that what ever the issue is when i run the exact same code i provided on another machine it works as expected. Ill look into your code and test to see if it runs on both machines. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

I got this error at this line:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor as executor:
```

**missing brackets** was the issue

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was intentionally defining a custom **with** function called *stopwatch*

```
with stopwatch('upload %d bytes' % len(data)):
    ...code...
```

And so had to add:

```
import contextlib
```

and prefix the custom function definition as follows:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def stopwatch(message):
    ...code...
```

Answer (score -1):

My problem was that I was expecting `os.open` to work like the built-in `open`...

This results in `AttributeError: __enter__`

```
import os 
with os.open('out.txt', os.CREAT) as f:
  f.write('hello world')
```

This does not

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write('hello world')
```

I suppose it would be easy enough to cause the OP problem with `from os import open`.