# AttributeError: __enter__ when loading in json file

Tags: python, json, file-io

I'm trying to read in and parse a json file, I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I had this working earlier today but after I updated and restarted Spyder it wouldn't work. I've now tried it with vscode as well and am running into the same error.

```
with open(r"C:\Users\Eric\OneDrive\GUI Proj\NBA_schedule.json") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
sched_access = data['leagueSchedule']
gameDates = sched_access['gameDates']
```

I got this json file from this link
https://cdn.nba.com/static/json/staticData/scheduleLeagueV2.json
and have tried both json.load() and json.loads() as well as not using the with open method. But I am continuing to get errors. What am I missing here?

EDIT: It has to do with one of my imports...somehow

Comment: read this also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564755/python-error-attributeerror-enter

Comment: "It has to do with one of my imports" *which you haven't shown*.  Make a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

For me is working this example with the same json file that I have downloaded (copied in a local file)

```
import json

with open('1.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    
season = data['leagueSchedule']['seasonYear']
league = data['leagueSchedule']['leagueId']

print(season)
print(league)
```

**Output:**

```
2021-22
00
```