# Mocking functions from object created by context manager

Tags: python-2.7, mocking, python-mock

I have the following module that I am trying to write unit tests for.

```
import myModuleWithCtxMgr

def myFunc(arg1):
    with myModuleWithCtxMgr.ctxMgr() as ctxMgr:
        result = ctxMgr.someFunc()

    if result:
        return True, result
    return False, None
```

The unit tests I'm working on looks like this.

```
import mock
import unittest
import myModule as myModule

class MyUnitTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch("myModuleWithCtxMgr.ctxMgr")
    def testMyFunc(self, mockFunc):
        mockReturn = mock.MagicMock()
        mockReturn.someFunc = mock.Mock(return_value="val")
        mockFunc.return_value = mockReturn
        result = myModule.myFunc("arg")

        self.assertEqual(result, (True, "val"))
```

The test is failing because result[0] = magicMock() and not the return value (I thought) I configured.

I've tried a few different variations of the test but I can't seem to be able to mock the return value of ctxMgr.someFunc(). Does anyone know how I might accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says:

```
First differing element 1:
<MagicMock name='ctxMgr().__enter__().someFunc()' id='139943278730000'>
'val'

- (True, <MagicMock name='ctxMgr().__enter__().someFunc()' id='139943278730000'>)
+ (True, 'val')
```

The error contains the mock name which exactly shows you what needs to be mocked. Note that `__enter__` corresponds to the [Context Manager protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1984346).

This works for me:

```
class MyUnitTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch("myModuleWithCtxMgr.ctxMgr")
    def testMyFunc(self, mockCtxMgr):
        mockCtxMgr().__enter__().someFunc.return_value = "val"
        result = myModule.myFunc("arg")

        self.assertEqual(result, (True, "val"))
```

Note how each of these is a separate `MagicMock` instance which you can configure:

- `mockCtxMgr`
- `mockCtxMgr()`
- `mockCtxMgr().__enter__`
- `mockCtxMgr().__enter__()`
- `mockCtxMgr().__enter__().someFunc`

MagicMocks are created lazily but have identity, so you can configure them this way and it Just Works.