# tf.GradientTape can't watch outside 'with' block

Tags: python, tensorflow, syntax, gradient, with-statement

TensorFlow tutorials on tensorflow.org show the way to use `tf.GradientTape` as:

```
x = tf.convert_to_tensor([1,2,3]);
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
  t.watch(x);
```

I wonder why I can't move the `t.watch(x)` outside of `with` block like this:

```
x = tf.convert_to_tensor([1,2,3]);
t = tf.GradientTape();
t.watch(x); #ERROR
```

The error is:

```
tape.py (59):
pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_Py_TapeWatch(tape._tape, tensor)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_tape'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how. The `tf.GradientTape` class is designed to work within `with` block, ie. it has **enter** and **exit** methods.

So to have it working outside 'with' block, method `__enter__` must be explicitly called, however, avoid calling `__enter__` directly:

```
x = tf.convert_to_tensor([1,2,3]);
t = tf.GradientTape();
t.__enter__();
t.watch(x);
```

Reference:
[Explaining Python's '__enter__' and '__exit__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984325/explaining-pythons-enter-and-exit)