# Where do the three arguments come from in this __exit__ function extending a python base type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, metaprogramming

I tried to play around with the built in string type, wondering if I could use strings with the `with` syntax. Obviously the following will fail:

```py
with "hello" as hello:
    print(f"{hello} world!")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Then, just deriving a class from `str` with the two needed attributes for `with`:

```py
class String(str):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self):
        ...

with String("hello") as hello:
    print(f"{hello} world!")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: __exit__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

Ok, I wonder what those arguments are.., I added `*args, **kwargs` to `__exit__`, and then tried it again:

```py
class String(str):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("args: ", args)
        print("kwargs: ", kwargs)

with String("hello") as hello:
    print(f"{hello} world!")

hello world!
args:  (None, None, None)
kwargs:  {}
```

Works with different types too that I guess can be normally called with `str()`, but what are those three arguments? How do I go about finding more information on what the three extra arguments were? I guess finally, where can I go to see the implementation of built-in types, etc...?

Comment: Check out this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984325/explaining-pythons-enter-and-exit

Comment: https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/exit_must_accept_three_arguments.html

Comment: Ah I see, the link @schwobaseggl suggested was quite useful, aSimon Crane also.  Makes complete sense now what those three arguments are! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

These are actually methods(`__enter__()` & `__exit__()`) of contextmanager class. Please refer to this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__exit__#context-manager-types) for detailed explaination.

The `__exit__()` method will exit the runtime context and return a Boolean flag indicating if any exception that occurred should be suppressed

Those three arguments are:

1. exception_type
2. exception_value
3. traceback

The values of these arguments contain information regarding the thrown exception. **If the values equal to None means no exception was thrown.**