# What is needed upon __exit__ in a Python context manager?

Tags: python, contextmanager

I am trying to write a context manager function. It "works", but I have noticed that the `__repr__` method from the context continues to fire even after the "with" has exited.

Here is the TimedContext class:

```
import time

class TimedContext:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = self.now = self.duration = 0

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        return self

    def __format__(self, spec):
        self._update_duration()
        return format(self.duration, spec)

    def __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback):
        self._update_duration()
        return traceback is None

    def _update_duration(self):
        self.now = time.time()
        self.duration = self.now - self.start
```

Here is me using it:

```
from TimedContext import TimedContext
import time

with TimedContext() as t:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f"Time0: {t}")

print(f"Time1: {t}")
time.sleep(1)
print(f"Time2: {t}")
```

Here is my output running the script:

```
Time0: 1.001316785812378
Time1: 1.0014879703521729
Time2: 2.0025713443756104
```

I had expected Time2 to be the same as Time1 since I expected the end of the `with` completed the context so that `t` would now just be a variable containing the final return from the context.  (do I have my wording right here?)

The reason I am updating the TimedContext within the `__format__` function is that I want to be able to reference `t` from both inside and outside the "with".  If I did not update here, `t` would be correct after the `__exit__` was run, but inside the with, it would just be the `__init__` value.

I can fix this "issue" by creating a boolean `exit_called`, setting it to False on `__init__` and True on `__exit__` and then only update `self.duration` if `exit_called` is False.  While this "works", I was expecting the context to be gone since the `with` completed and `__exit__` has run to completion.  However, it appears the context sticks around.  Is it deterministic how long?  When does the context get cleaned up?  I had assumed the closing of the `with` did that.  Is there something I need to do to allow the context to be cleaned up, or do I need to explicitly do it?

I'd like to understand what should be going on here.  I wasn't expecting the context to stick around once `__exit__` completes.  Maybe I should be addressing my problem a different way?

Comment: "Once the "with" completes, the context is done and Python cleans it up for me." - what? No, if you're writing a context manager, writing the cleanup is *your* job. That's what `__exit__` is for. Python has no idea what kind of cleanup your context manager needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explaining Python's '__enter__' and '__exit__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984325)

Comment: I added python code that replicates my issue.  Is this sufficient?  Please read my question, I solved (worked around?) my problem by editing the `__exit__` function.  I was never expecting my `__exit__` to be written for me, I was expecting the context itself to be cleaned up.  I thought that was the whole point of the `with` statement.

Comment: I appreciate the pointer to a possible duplicate but I read those posts and don't see any relevant data to my question.  Maybe referencing `__exit__` is not correct and I should ask for how long after the ending of a `with` that the `__format__` method sticks around?  Does that make sense?

Comment: Your `__format__` method calls `self._updateDuration()`. This will, of course, update the timer. A good reminder to not mix business logic and string formatting...

Comment: Ok, my ultimate goal here is to use this context manager and be able to reference the time both from outside the with AND inside.  If I reference `t` inside the with, it appears that calls the `__format__` method.  Maybe this is a secondary call?  This was how I was able to get the reference inside the `with` working.  Where else would I run `self._updateDuration()`?

Comment: Also, am I using the terminology correctly?  How I interpreted what was going on here (seem I am wrong?) is that the `with` instantiates the context which I have written as TimedContext.  When the `with` closes, it kicks off the `__exit__` function.  What I was assuming was that at this point, the context is destroyed (isn't that the point of the `with`?) and the `as t` t variable would then hold whatever TimedContext finally returned.  This seems not to be the case as context methods still run when the `with` is done.

Comment: Being called a `Context Manager`, I thought the `with` was what managed the context, no?

Comment: @stauf the format method is called when you use f-strings. And as it updates the time, you will get a different value every time. That design issue can be solved in various ways; personally I would drop the `self.now` field entirely, change `_updateDuration` to calculate `time.time() - self.start`, only call it in `__exit__`, and add a new `getDuration` method (or equivalent property) as `return time.time() - self.start if duration = 0 else duration`. So in effect, calculate the duration on the fly while you're in the `with`, store it in `self.duration` on exit, and use that afterwards.

Comment: The `t` variable is initialized at the start of the `with` statement, and sticks around afterwards as long as you don't change scope (e.g. if the `with` is in a method definition, the variable is lost after the method returns). After the `with`, `t` still contains the same object, which is mutable so you can overwrite its fields with whatever you want, as happens in your __format__method. BTW, personally I think f-strings are usually a code smell, and you could simply ditch `__format__`, use `__str__` instead, and use `print("Time:", t)` instead of the f-string.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that is helpful.  So, how "should" I address this situation?  If I don't do the _updateDuration in the `__format__ (or `__str__`) method then t won't have a value other than `__init__` until the `__exit__` method is run.  I worked around what I wanted by including a boolean in the TimedContext class that is False until the `__exit__` has run.  The _updateDuration  only updates if `__exit_` has not yet been run.  While this works, it just doesn't feel right, like I am missing the "correct" way to do this.  Makes me worry I might be missing another corner case.

Answer (score 2):

From [Unraveling the `with` statement](https://snarky.ca/unravelling-the-with-statement/):

> ```
> with a as b:
>     body...
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> _enter = type(a).__enter__
> _exit = type(a).__exit__
> b = _enter(a)
>
> try:
>    body...
> except:
>    if not _exit(a, *sys.exc_info()):
>        raise
> else:
>    _exit(a, None, None, None)
> ```

`with` doesn't do any cleanup of its own, it calls the `__exit__()` method to do that. It also doesn't delete the `b` variable -- it still contains the value that was assigned by `as b`.

For example, when you use

```
with open(filename) as f:
    code...

print(f)
```

`f` will still contain the file object, but it will be closed and unusable because its `__exit__()` method closes the file and reclaims any resources.

This is no different from other constructs that assign variables for use in a block. For instance, the variable in a `for` statement can be used after the loop is done -- it will contain the value from the last iteration.

The context manager object itself will eventually be cleaned up by the garbage collector, when the variable goes out of scope.

Comment: I appreciate the comment but this has nothing to do with my question.  I edited my `__exit__` function to work around my issue.  My issue is about when/how the context itself is cleaned up, not the actual running of the `__exit__` method.  I know when that runs.

Comment: It's cleaned up like any other object -- by the garbage collector when it becomes garbage.