# When to use close() and __del__() in Pyserial?

Tags: python, pyserial

According to [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html?highlight=setdtr#serial.Serial.read), class `serial.Serial()` has the following methods.

```
close()
Close port immediately.

__del__()
Destructor, close port when serial port instance is freed.
```

I would like to know when I should use `close()` and `__del__()`? Example, I have a GUI that created an instance of `serial.Serial()` with an assigned port. According to documentation, the assigned port will be opened when the instance of `serial.Serial()`. Now when I terminate my GUI, am I correct to say that `__del__()` (and not `close()`) is the most appropriate method to use to close the serial port?

Comment: When you terminate the GUI `__del__()` will be called automtically...

Comment: @StephenRauch By any chance to you know where this instruction is stated in the serial.py module? I could not find it. Can you help show me the location of this instruction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Analysis

If we look at [pyserial source](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/a4d8f27bf636ee598c4368d7e488f78a226bf778/serial/serialutil.py#L163) we see:

```
class SerialBase(io.RawIOBase):
```

Aha! Let's look into [io.RawIOBase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase):

> Base class for raw binary I/O. It inherits `IOBase`. There is no public constructor.

OK. Looking for `__del__` in `IOBase` we see:

> `__del__()`
>   Prepare for object destruction. `IOBase` provides a default implementation of this method that calls the instance’s `close()` method.

## Conclusion

You can use `close()` or `del` or `with`-context - they all close the port.

Comment: Thank you. Noted that `.__del__()` method in the `serial.Serial()` object is really a method from python's `io.IOBase()` object. After reading other SO discussions on `__del__ ()`, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481488/what-is-the-del-method-how-to-call-it) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37852560/is-del-really-a-destructor), I learnt that [`__del__()` is really a Python Special Method name](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) that is used to customize the finalization of a python object.

Comment: The execution of `__del__()` can be problematic according to Python documentation. If so, I am thinking that in situations where I no longer require the port in an instance of the `serial.Serial()` object to be opened, I should promptly close the port using the `.close()` method instead of the `.__del__()` method.

Comment: There is nothing problematic itself in calling `__methods__` - it's just looking strange to call them directly. E.g. `someobject.__del__()` instead of `del someobject`

Comment: If you look at source you can also see `__exit__` method that automaticaly calls `close()`. So: call whatever you want - result will be same.