# del MyClass doesn't call object.__del__()

Tags: python, destructor

I have a class that opens a file for writing. In my destructor, I call the function that closes the file:

```
class MyClass:
    def __del__(self):
        self.close()

    def close(self):
        if self.__fileHandle__ is not None:
                self.__fileHandle__.close()
```

but when I delete the object with code like:

```
myobj = MyClass()
myobj.open()
del myobj
```

if I try to reinstantiate the object, I get a value error:

```
ValueError: The file 'filename' is already opened.  Please close it before reopening in write mode.
```

whereas if I call `myobj.close()` before `del myobj` I don't get this problem. So why isn't `__del__()` getting called?

Comment: Try inheriting from `object` - not doing so has been considered out-of-date style for some six years.

Comment: You should show some more code. How can one tell you how `myobj.close()` changes things, without knowing what it does?

Comment: Keep in mind that `del` doesn't call `__del__`. It just removes one of the references. Generally it's better to close explicitly, possibly using the context manager protocol (`with` statement).

Comment: @Marcin - that solved it ... post as an answer? Still curious as to why this should be the case ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure you want to use `__del__`? There are [issues](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) with `__del__` and garbage collection.

You could make MyClass a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) instead:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self,ext_type,exc_value,traceback):
        if self.__fileHandle__ is not None:
                self.__fileHandle__.close()
```

By doing so, you could use `MyClass` like this:

```
with MyClass() as myobj:
    ...
```

and `myobj.__exit__` (and thus `self.__fileHandle__.close()`) will be called when Python leaves the `with-block`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the issues.  http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.garbage says that «Objects that have __del__() methods and are part of a reference cycle cause the entire reference cycle to be uncollectable, including objects not necessarily in the cycle but reachable only from it.»

Comment: I don't see how there's a reference cycle in the OP's example. There's one object, it gets `del`'d, and `__del__()` doesn't get called.

Comment: Also, in my situation, I'd rather let the GC handle stuff as it doesn't need to all get closed immediately, just eventually... but it always has problems. And no, context managers are not a real solution. They restrict you to closing the object within the same function call and indent your code one level every time you use one. Makes it unreadable when I want to create 20 of these.

Answer (score 8):

That's not what `del` does.  It's unfortunate that `__del__` has the same name as `del`, because they are not related to each other.  In modern terminology, the `__del__` method would be called a *finalizer*, not a *destructor* and the difference is important.

The short difference is that it's easy to guarantee when a destructor is called, but you have very few guarantees about when `__del__` will be called and it might *never* be called.  There are many different circumstances that can cause this.

If you want lexical scoping, use a `with` statement.  Otherwise, call `myobj.close()` directly.  The `del` statement only deletes references, not objects.

I found another answer ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1481512/82294)) to a different question that answers this in more detail.  It is unfortunate that the accepted answer to that question contains egregious errors.

**Edit:** As commentors noted, you need to inherit from `object`.  That is fine, but it is still possible that `__del__` will never be called (you could be getting lucky).  See the linked answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should inherit from `object` - not doing so has been considered out of date (except in special cases) for at least six years.

You can read about `__del__` here:   [http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.**del**](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)

The short version of why you need to inherit from `object` is that `__del__` is only "magic" on new-style classes.

If you need to rely on calling of a finalizer, I strongly suggest that you use the context manager approach recommended in other answers, because that is a portable, robust solution.

Comment: Ah just found an instance where this "magic" doesn't work ... using ipython instead.

Comment: @tdc: Unless I'm mistaken, ipython is based on cpython. In any case, if you rely on the behaviour of a particular instance, your code will be non-portable. It would probably be better to use the context manager approach recommended in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something else is referencing it, which is why `__del__` isn't being called (yet).

Consider this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

class NiceClass():
    def __init__(self, num):
        print "Make %i" % num
        self.num = num
    def __del__(self):
        print "Unmake %i" % self.num

x = NiceClass(1)
y = NiceClass(2)
z = NiceClass(3)
lst = [x, y, z]
time.sleep(1)
del x
del y
del z
time.sleep(1)
print "Deleting the list."
del lst
time.sleep(1)
```

It doesn't call `__del__` of `NiceClass` instances until we delete the list that references them.

Unlike C++, `__del__` isn't being called unconditionally to destruct the object on demand.  GC makes things a bit harder.  Here is some info: http://arctrix.com/nas/python/gc/

Comment: There was definitely only one reference in this case