# Python: Understanding object __del__ method

Tags: python

Can anyone describe me why this code will print '2 1 0 done' instead of expected output '0 1 2 done'? 
As i can understand, we have some anonymous variables creating during list comprehensions, and they are garbage-collected, using filo principle, on list comprehension uncoverage end.
But, they still are referenced in list aa, aren't they?
Why the second 'del a' is not calling **del** magic method in that case?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __del__(self):
        print self.name,

aa = [A(str(i)) for i in range(3)]
for a in aa:
    del a

print 'done'
```

Also, advanced questions. Please look at http://codepad.org/niaUzGEy
Why there are 5 copies, 3 copies? Musn't this be 1 copy? Why 5 or 3? Dont know, thats why asking it ;)
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Don't put two questions into a single question. Make two questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1481512/367273

Answer (score 7):

You are confusing the `del` statement and the `__del__` method.

`del a` simply unbinds the name `a` from whatever object it referenced. The list referenced by `aa` is unchanged so the objects all continue to exist.

The `__del__` method is only called after the last reference to an object has been destroyed. That could be after a call to `__del__` but usually isn't.

You rarely need to use `del`. It would be much more common just to rebind `aa` and then all the objects it contains will be released, and if not otherwise referenced their `__del__` methods will be called automatically.

Also, you rarely need to use `__del__`. For most purposes Python's management of objects will handle cleanup automatically. Adding a `__del__` method to a class is generally a bad idea as it can interfere with the garbage collector, so rather paradoxically `__del__` makes it more likely that your program will leak memory. Also Python won't guarantee whether `__del__` is actually called on program exit, and if it does you may find global variables you cant to use no longer exist, nor will it guarantee to only call it once (though you have to jump through hoops to make it call it more than once).

In short, avoid using `__del__` if you possibly can.

Answer (score 3):

It prints `done 2 1 0`(CPython).

You don't delete list elements in a for loop. They are deleted on exit. As far as I know call order of `__del__` is implementation-specific, so it can be different in another implementations(IronPython, Jython etc.)

Comment: On pypy, `2 1 0` isn't even printed at all.