# are there method's to make a thread sleep before it quits?

Tags: python, class

```
import  time

class tA(obj):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __del__(self):
        time.sleep(5)
```

I found that, when the class `tA` is destroyed, it did not delay for 5 seconds.
Why? And how to add delay?

are there method's to make a thread sleep before it quits?

Comment: [Don't use the `__del__` method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2452895/2846140)

Comment: What do you mean when the *class* is destroyed? `__del__` is called when *instances* are destroyed. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: How do you try to delete your instance ? Using `del instance_of_tA` ?

Comment: I want to wait a thread running a little time, before closed by sys

Comment: @王王王 I think it would be better if you ask that question instead, there are method's to make a thread sleep before it quits - even in the case of exceptions raised in the thread. Probably there is a solution that better suits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually works. You're probably confused by the fact that the object isn't being destroyed when you think it is - it may be destroyed at a later moment. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) for more details, note especially that `del x` is not guaranteed to call `x.__del__`.

In general you should not use `__del__` if you haven't got good enough reason to do so (and I actually don't think you have), and reasons good enough are rare.

Cases where I found that the function is actually called is for example:

```
x = tA()
x = None # __del__ is called in my python

tA() # __del__ is called in my python

x = tA()
exit # __del__ is called in my python

x = tA()
del x # __del__ is NOT called in my python
```

As for making a thread sleep before it quits you'll need to put the sleep in the thread code (note that `__del__` might run in any thread and when the thread has already terminated), for example:

```
class tA(Thread):
    def run(self):
        try:
            do_your_stuff()
        finally:
            time.sleep(5)
```

note that `finally` makes sure that `time.sleep(5)` is called whether `do_your_stuff()` returns sucessfully or raises exception.

Answer (score -2):

```
>>> import time
>>> class test():
...     def __init__(self):
...             print "a"
...             time.sleep(5)
...     def __del__(self):
...             print "b"
...
>>> a=test()
a
b
>>>
```

For example it's working.
If need call "sleep" in the last function of class.

Comment: First of all it behaves different from the OP's intention (since the sleep is at init time), second it does not behave the way you state.