# How to write unit test case for Python __del__ function

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following code setup, and I have a test case to test the `Db.__init__` already, how do I test the `__del__`? Can you provide an example?

```
import psycopg2


class Db(object):
    def __init__(self):
        import app
        conn_string = "host='{}' port='{}' dbname='{}' user='{}' password='{}'".format(app.app.config['DB_HOST'], \
                      app.app.config['DB_PORT'], app.app.config['DB_NAME'], app.app.config['DB_USER'], \
                      app.app.config['DB_PASSWORD'])
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

    def __del__(self):
        self.conn.close()
```

Test Case

```
@ddt
class TestDB(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('psycopg2.connect')
    def test_db_constructor(self, mock_psycopg2_connect):
        mock_psycopg2_connect.returned_value = True
        db = Db()

        self.assertTrue(db.conn)
```

Comment: You have a typo, it should be `mock_psycopg2_connect.return_value`.

Comment: You should not be using `__del__` (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481488/what-is-the-del-method-how-to-call-it/2452895#2452895)).  Maybe you could solve your problem with a [`with` statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Just call the method directly, having mocked out `self.conn` via the `__init__` method:

```
@patch('psycopg2.connect')
def test_db_destructor(self, mock_psycopg2_connect):
    db = Db()
    mock_conn = mock_psycopg2_connect.return_value
    close = mock_conn.close

    db.__del__()
    close.assert_called_once()
```

Your original test has a flaw; you misspelled `return_value`, so your mock connect never returns `True`; it returns a new mock object. That mock object just *happens* to have a true value:

```
>>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock
>>> mock = MagicMock()
>>> mock.connect()
<MagicMock name='mock.connect()' id='4536051752'>
>>> bool(mock.connect())
True
```

To properly test that the `connect()` method return value is stored in `db.conn`, test if that attribute is the exact same object as what the mock returns:

```
@patch('psycopg2.connect')
def test_db_constructor(self, mock_psycopg2_connect):
    mock_conn = mock_psycopg2_connect.return_value

    db = Db()
    self.assertTrue(db.conn is mock_conn)
```