# What is the danger of __del__ in python?

Tags: python, destructor, del

Every post or article on `__del__` warns about circular references and the fact that its execution is not guaranteed. But what are the dangers of using `__del__` except non-guaranteed execution? For example:

1. I want to write a `__del__` method in a class to be called explicitly on its objects `myobject.__del__()`. Why is it a bad idea?
2. What is the risk of multiple calls to `myobject.__del__()`?

Comment: The duplicate has very detailed answers that should address your questions. If not, let me know.

Comment: I've seen those answers, but they don't explain if my kind of usage is a bad idea. Also there's nothing regarding multiple calls to `myobject.__del__()`.

Comment: Alright, reopened.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the \_\_del\_\_ method, How to call it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481488/what-is-the-del-method-how-to-call-it)