# Python program bombs out after finishing

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm getting a strange Python error. I'm executing a file that looks like this.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyClass().main()
    print('Done 1')
    print('Done 2')
```

The preceding runs successfully.  But when I change it to this, I get the strange result.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    myObject = MyClass()
    myObject.main()
    print('Done 1')
    print('Done 2')
```

The output looks like this.

```
Done 1
Done 2
Exception ignored in: <function Viewer.__del__ at 0x0000021569EF72F0> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\classic_control\rendering.py", line 143, in __del__
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\classic_control\rendering.py", line 62, in close
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.py", line 305, in close
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\__init__.py", line 770, in close
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down

Process finished with exit code 0
```

There is a blank line after the final `print` line. The same thing happens when the final line does not have an end-of-line marker.

I get the same result whether I run it from within PyCharm using the `run` command or from the terminal.

As you can probably tell from the error lines, the program generates an animation. (It's the cart-pole problem from OpenAI gym.)

Since the program completes before the error, it's not a disaster. But I'd like to understand what's happening.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to add `env.close()` to your code, for more details see: https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/893#issuecomment-369519156

Comment: does adding `import gc; gc.collect()` after the print statements prevent the output?

Comment: Can you provide the code for MyClass or a minimum case which reproduces this bug - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: @alfasin. Adding `env.close()` as the last line in `main` solved the problem. Thanks. Interestingly, the cart-pole environment terminates an episode only when the cart or pole go out of bounds. Otherwise one can `step` forever. So if the program that calls `env.step()` terminates the episode after some number of steps, the environment is left hanging in what it thinks is the middle of an episode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python provides a `__del__` dunder method for classes that will be called as the instances are garbage collected, [*if they're garbage collected*.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481488/what-is-the-del-method-how-to-call-it)

When it's used, the `__del__` method typically performs some sort of cleanup.

Due to the fact that it's fairly easy to inadvertently prevent an object from being collected, reliance on the `__del__` to perform cleanup (instead of say, a context manager's `__exit__` or an explicit `.close()` method) is generally advised against.

Your error highlights a different reason for avoiding relying on `__del__`, however: that during shutdown `__del__` will be called but possibly after other things *that it relies on are freed*.

The proposed workarounds on the github issue linked in the comments should be instructive, as they all ensure that the cleanup is done at a time where the things that that cleanup relies on (e.g. `sys.meta_path`) are still in defined/not yet freed, e.g.:

```
try:
    del env
except ImportError:
    pass
```

and

```
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
...
env.env.close()
```

and (likely, but much less efficient or clear)

```
import gc; gc.collect()
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For those interested in why it came up in this context, please also see my comment on the original question.