# Function that replaces .txt file \n (new line) with _ (underscore)?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that takes a filename as its argument and returns a string with all `\n` characters replaced by the `_` character.

This is what I did:

```
def replace_space(filename):
    wordfile = open(filename)
    text_str = wordfile.read()
    wordfile.close()
    text_str.replace("\n", "_")

replace_space("words.txt")
```

I also tried using " " instead of "\n":

```
    text_str.replace(" ", "_")
```

Comment: Add a `return` statement to your function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python, unlike languages such as Haskell and Scala, will return `None` if it reaches the end of a function body without an explicit return statement. Therefore, you want this:

```
def replace_space(filename):
    with open(filename) as wordfile:
        text_str = wordfile.read()

    return text_str.replace("\n", "_")
```

Note also the use of `with` in place of `open` and `close`; it ensures your file gets closed even if you get an exception somewhere along the way.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using with? curious.

Comment: @puppyonkik `with` is basically syntactic sugar for `try-finally`; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56050594/resource-aquisition-is-initialization-in-python/56050631#56050631) of mine.

Comment: But since `text_str` is defined inside of the `with`, won't it give a NameError on return if it can't open the file because it is trying to return a variable that is not defined?

Comment: @funie200 No, because if `open` can't open the file, then it will itself raise an exception, so you won't even get to the `return`.

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions for your code

- You can use `with` context manager to open your file which will take care of closing the file for you
- You need return back the updated string.

```
def replace_space(filename):
    text_str = ''
    #Open the file and read the contents
    with open(filename) as wordfile:
        text_str = wordfile.read()

    #Replace and return the updated string
    return text_str.replace("\n", "_")

replace_space("file.txt")
```

If you don't want to use the context manager, you need to explicitly open and close the file like you were doing before

```
def replace_space(filename):
    text_str = ''

    #Open the file
    wordfile = open(filename)
    #Do the read and replace
    text_str = wordfile.read().replace("\n", "_")

    #Close file and return updated string
    wordfile.close()
    return text_str

replace_space("file.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        text = file.read()
    text = text.replace('\n', '_')
    return text
```