# reference to a deleted object in python

Tags: python, reference

Firstly, I know object is destruct(or destroyed) when its `__del__` function called by `gc` implicitly or called explicitly. ok, why I could get the object's member variable by its reference after this object was destroyed.

python version is 3.7.1

```py
class O():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'I am a O'
    def __del__(self):
        print('Oops, O is deleted')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    o = O()
    c = o
    print(id(o))
    o.__del__()
    print(c.name)
    print(id(c))
```

**The result**

```
2473601495560
Oops, O is deleted
I am a O
2473601495560
Oops, O is deleted
```

We could find the problem exists, and the destruct function was called 2 times but why. thanks for help

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481488/what-is-the-del-method-how-to-call-it . `o.__del__` **doesn't** delete `o`, it's just a method that will be called when `o` is destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some ground truths.

- CPython uses *reference counting*. Objects are de-allocated when their reference count drops to 0.
- Not all objects are handled by the `gc` module. From the documentation:

  > As a general rule, instances of atomic types aren’t tracked and instances of non-atomic types (containers, user-defined objects…) are.
- Python "variables" are actually *names* that *reference* objects.

So when you do `c = o`, you create a second reference to the same class `O` instance that `o` references. That is why they have the same `id`.

**By definition**, when an object is de-allocated, *there are no more references to it*. So you cannot get a reference to it anymore.

**Edit:**
Your impression of `__del__` seems kind of upside-down. It wil generally be called by Python after the reference count has reached 0, see the [relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__).
But if *your program* calls an object's `__del__` method, that does not magically remove all references! See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1481512/1219295) (and the documentation mentioned before) for the a more detailed explanation.

Double underscore methods (or "dunder" methods) are for Python to use internally to provide some functionality. You should as a rule not call them from your program.