# Python Classes __del__ Method

Tags: python

I'm sorry if the topic in wrong section

I'm curious about Python classes `__del__` method:

Example:

```
class A():
    [...]

class B():
    __init__:
        self.a = A()
    __del__:
        del self.a

b = B()
del b
```

Do I have to write `__del__` method on `class B`?
Is `A class` instance in `B class` remove from memory when remove `B` instance or we must use `__del__` method like mine?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481488/what-is-the-del-method-how-to-call-it This may help. `Since you have no guarantee it's executed, one should never put the code that you need to be run into __del__()`

Comment: You never normally need a del method. The usage as shown should not need it. btw methods need brackets:  def x(self):

Comment: `del b` should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

When the `B` object is destroyed (after it is “finalized”), its reference `a` evaporates, so the `del a` at *most* adjusts the timing of the destruction of the `A` object (in a way that is unobservable with the code shown here).  “At most” because the timing (or even occurrence) of object finalization/destruction is completely unspecified except that finalization precedes destruction and neither happens while the object is referenced.