# Methods invoked when Python class garbage collected

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection

I am trying to find out if it is possible that a method exists out there in the python class that is invoked before or during garbage collection.

What i intend to do is to close any database connection just before a  class is garbage collected.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481488/what-is-the-del-method-how-to-call-it

Comment: Yes it most certainly does! Thanks!