# How variable gets created and destroy in python?

Tags: python, memory-management, interpreter

If we create 2 variables a followed by b, then how these variable gets destroy in python heap.
We want to understand the memory management done by python interpreter.

Comment: Garbage collection: https://stackify.com/python-garbage-collection/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Releasing memory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455048/releasing-memory-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Simply putting, Python memory manager counts references to the existing variables and if reference count is equal to zero, garbage collector automatically de-allocates the space for that variable.

I'd recommend following resources to better understand the flow:

1. https://realpython.com/python-memory-management/
2. https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html

Comment: exactly which variable will get deleted first?

Answer (score 0):

Order is undefined as python has a garbage collector. To trace the order you may add a `__del__` method which is known as a destructor method in Python. It is called when there are no  references to the object and object is garbage collected.

See [What is the __del__ method, How to call it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481488/what-is-the-del-method-how-to-call-it)