# Why is the object not getting deleted and reinstantiated when I call the del function in the below code?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, object, instantiation

Why is the object not getting deleted and reinstantiated when I call the del function in the below code?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a={}):
        if not ('1' in a):
            a['1']=1
        else:
            a['1']+=1

        print (a['1'])

    def __del__(self):
        del self.a

for i in range (5):
    a=A()
```

output:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

expected output:

```
1,1,1,1,1
```

Comment: Where do you call the "del" function? (There is no function called `del`, do you mean `__del__`?)

Comment: Can you explain *why* you expected `1,1,1,1,1` as output?

Comment: Since you already have answer to the problem you are facing below, just looking over what you are trying to achieve there, take a look at collections.defaultdict instead

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. What i want to achieve is once the object is created then " if not ('1' in a): a['1']=1 " this line should get executed every time since every time the __del__ would get called and the object would cease to exist. Isn't it expected that __del__  would just delete the object every time it's called? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: **If** `__del__` is called. Where do you expect that it is called?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481488/what-is-the-del-method-how-to-call-it

Answer (score 2):

When you use a mutable item as default param in the init of a class it will be shared across all instances that created in the same scope.
You need to create a dict in each init of class instances like

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a=None):
        a = {} if not a else a
        if not ('1' in a):
            a['1']=1
        else:
            a['1']+=1

        print (a['1'])


for i in range(5):
    a=A()
```

Output

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: There's also no need to define `__del__` in this case; if the instance of `A` can be garbage-collected, so can the `dict` referenced (only) by its `a` attribute.

Comment: That's right I will remove it from the answer, Tnx for that