# Why __del__() is called

Tags: python

```
class Data:
    def __del__(self):
        print('Data.__del__')

class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = Data()
        self.parent = None
        self.children = []

    def add_child(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)
        child.parent = self

a = Node()
del a
```

As a result, `Data.__del__` is printed, why `__del__()` funtion in class Data is called?

Comment: Are you under the impression that `__del__` is a `del` hook? It's not.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/destructors-in-python/

Comment: It seems to me like it is because `a` has a member variable of type `Data`. When `a` gets deleted, then `a.data` gets deleted as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481488/what-is-the-del-method-how-to-call-it