# ModuleNotFoundError: import of time halted; None in sys.modules occured when Object gets out of scope(__del__)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a Class

```
import os
import math
from datetime import datetime


class Log:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.log_name = f"{file_name}.log"
        self.log = open(os.path.abspath(self.log_name), 'a+')
        if os.stat(self.log_name).st_size == 0:
            self.add_log('START')

    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self.add_log('FINISH')
            self.log.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def add_log(self, text):
        self.log.write(f"{self.now()} {self.message(text)}\n")
        self.log.flush()
        os.fsync(self.log)

    def now(self):
        return str(datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'))

    def message(self, text):
        tot_len = 70
        ret_text = str(f"[{'-'*tot_len}]")
        return ret_text[:(tot_len//2)-(len(text)//2)] + text + ret_text[(tot_len//2)+math.ceil(len(text)/2):]
```

The purpose of my class is to create logs.
In another file, let's say `demo.py`, I imported this

```
from log import Log

obj = Log('demo01')

obj.add_log('THis is line 1')
obj.add_log('THis is line 2')
obj.add_log('THis is line 3')
obj.add_log('THis is line 4')
obj.add_log('THis is line 5')
```

I have got a file `demo01.log` in which

```
22-04-2021 23:08:44 [--------------------------------START---------------------------------]
22-04-2021 23:08:44 [---------------------------THis is line 1-----------------------------]
22-04-2021 23:08:44 [---------------------------THis is line 2-----------------------------]
22-04-2021 23:08:44 [---------------------------THis is line 3-----------------------------]
22-04-2021 23:08:44 [---------------------------THis is line 4-----------------------------]
22-04-2021 23:08:44 [---------------------------THis is line 5-----------------------------]
```

So, here comes the last part, the `__del__` raise an exception
`import of time halted; None in sys.modules` and
`FINISH` doesn't print in last line
So basically, I understood that `sys` get out of scope (I am guessing this has happen, correct me if I am wrong)

So, what could be solution for `__del__` to work without exception?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481488/what-is-the-del-method-how-to-call-it

Comment: Seems like it'd be much easier to write your class as a context manager rather than try to hack the "close" behavior with `__del__`

Comment: @buran`del obj` Worked for me! Thanks for suggesting this answer

Comment: @BallpointBen That's a nice idea too!

Comment: @rish_hyun - you completely misunderstood me. Don't hack `__del__`  for close behaviour.

Comment: Also if this is not some school project why not use `logging` module or some other logging tools available?

Comment: @buran No! That's not what I meant, I meant that I shall close the file by calling a function rather than depending on  `__del__`

Comment: @buran NO, it's not a school project, I am preparing a software :) I have saw `logging` but I want to make my own

Comment: You lost me with _`del obj` Worked for me_

Comment: @buran Well, `del obj` worked for me SO I am happy :) and I am going with it

Comment: do whatever you want but my advise is not to use `del obj` and `__del__` for what you are doing - that was my point. You clearly don't understand the `__del__` [special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__).

Comment: @buran Oh!! okay, That's was also given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481488/what-is-the-del-method-how-to-call-it that '__del__' shouldn't be use , so I shall not use `__del__` and `del` for destroying objects. Actually, I thoroughly gone through it now