# Delete method modification breaking my python script

Tags: python, postgresql, testing, mocking

I'm creating a Database class for testing. This is the basic idea; build a database at instantiation, test with it, then delete it when the testing is done. I'd like to use the `__del__` function to drop the schema when the object is destroyed.

```py
    def __init__(self):
        dbinfo = dbinfo
        with open('create_test_db_sql', 'r') as sql_file:
            query = sql_file.read()
        connection = self.connect_to_database()
        cur = connection.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        connection.commit()

    def connect_to_database(self):
        return psycopg2.connect(dbinfo)

    def __del__(self):
        print("done")
        conn = self.connect_to_database()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("DROP SCHEMA simulator_db_test CASCADE")
        connection.commit()
```

Whenever I try to run this I get this python error

```
Exception ignored in: <function TestDatabase.__del__ at 0x0000017AC504E430>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tests\TestDatabase.py", line 25, in __del__
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 121, in connect
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\extensions.py", line 163, in make_dsn
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\extensions.py", line 163, in <listcomp>
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\extensions.py", line 181, in _param_escape
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
```

Not sure what this error means and there don't seem to be any explanations out there except for specific situations.

What does this error mean? It only occurs when I try to connect to the database. I've tried running other code such as print statements and those run as expected in the `__del__` method.

Comment: So your are trying to override the builtin in `__del__` method and if so why? See this [__del__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481488/what-is-the-del-method-and-how-do-i-call-it) for the gotchas. Why not just make this `def drop_schema()`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver My end goal is to automate my tests using pytest and GitLab CI/CD. I wanted the Schema to be cleaned up automatically when the test database object is destroyed

Comment: Did you read the link I sent? My guess is you are being caught by object reference still in flight when you run the `__del__`. If you are dropping/deleting the database the schema is going to dropped as a part of that anyway as a `schema` is a 'child' of a database. Same on the other end the `schema` will be built as part of the database creation.

Comment: You could consider using an [atexit handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) to execute your teardown code safely.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I understand that, but if the __del__ method never runs, the schema will still exists on the local server. This should also run anywhere a postgre server is available

Comment: What I am saying is there is no reason to run the `__del__`. When you drop the database the schema goes with it.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I'm not ever dropping the database

Comment: Then you need to rewrite this: "...build a database at instantiation, test with it, then delete it when the testing is done.". When you do provide a detailed explanation of what you are doing and the code you are doing it with. FYI, the simplest thing would be to `DROP DATABASE ...` and then `CREATE DATABASE ...` for new test.