# Create a Tempfile with lifespan as the object

Tags: python, temporary-files

I have a project where I need to create temp files.

I have a class that accepts a file path. and as needed it reads the data from the file. However, sometimes I have the data and I want to create the same object so I use `tempfile`. But I want the file to be deleted as the object garbage-collected.

This is my implementation which is wrong.

```
from pickle import load
import tempfile


class A:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path

    @property
    def data(self):
        with open(self.file_path, "rb") as f2r:
            return load(f2r)

    @classmethod
    def from_data(cls, data):
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
            tmp.write(data)
            return cls(tmp.name)
```

The `from_data` method creates the temp file and returns an object but the file will be deleted as soon as `from_data` returns the object. But I want the file to live until the object itself is garbage-collected.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more robust to turn A into a context manager, and close the tempfile as part of the exit from your context manager?

Comment: I see what you say. But this example is a pseudo example of a more complex project and the design cannot be changed like that.

Comment: What if you overrode the finalizer, `__del__` so that it closes the tempfile when it is garbage collected? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481488/what-is-the-del-method-and-how-do-i-call-it

Comment: That's what I thought but I wanted to ask if there is a more elegant way to do so. But If you suggest so I'll implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Nick ODell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/530160/nick-odell) suggested I am going to use `__del__` method to delete the file on garbage-collection.

So the code would look like:

```
from pathlib import Path
from pickle import load
import tempfile


class A:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.is_temp = False

    def __del__(self):
        if self.is_temp:
            Path(self.file_path).unlink()

    @property
    def data(self):
        with open(self.file_path, "rb") as f2r:
            return load(f2r)

    @classmethod
    def from_data(cls, data):
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp:
            tmp.write(data)
            a = cls(tmp.name)
            a.is_temp = True
            return a
```